# router only assigns small number of IPs

Tags: wireless-networking

Been having a problem with my router for a while now, might just be because it is really old but here's the problem:

If a lot of computers are connected to my home network someone will get disconnected. They are assigned IPs and it seems like at a certain point (and I don't know how many) you either get assigned the same IP as someone else or something else is happening and you get disconnected - until i soft reset it and it works again which takes 30 secs.

I'd say my tablet, my PC, my sisters iPad, 2 laptops and a netbook is the most that can be connected at one time so that is 6 but that should be fine.

The only way I know this is the problem is because I turned on my tablet and I was online on my PC, got disconnected but my tablet was still connected, this is just after i turned the tablet on so I know my router is having difficulty with IPs, it is like it assigned the same IP to the tablet which then clashed with my desktop and knocked me off.

I see that sometimes the following solves it as well so I wrote a batch file with a menu to execute these commands as I have to do it so often.

```
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /renew
```

Any ideas? Or shall I just get a new router as this one is old and maybe can't handle giving out that many IPs?

Cheers!

Comment: Check the router's configuration. Make sure the DHCP pool is big enough.

Comment: Some ISP's control how many pc's can connect at one time.

Comment: @Liam: Before buying a new router first check the configuration of the current router. It might just be configured to only use a very small range for DHCP.

Comment: You can also set the DHCP address leases to a shorter time period.  Some routers set expiry to months.  Whensomeone connects once, they have an IP for however long the lease is.  Only an issue with users that are seldom connected